# In Symfony: How do I embed a form on its related entity, without including foreign key field (populate that on submission)?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have 3 Entities: Article, Author, Reivews:

**Relationships:**

- Article has One Author.
- Article has many Reviews.
- Author has many Articles.
- Review has One Author.
- Review has One Article.

Authors create both articles and reviews. They are the app's users.

I'm trying to embed a mix of the Author, Article, AND Review Entities on the Article's SHOW view. But only the inputs that the users (authors) will provide.

Use Case Example: a user (author) is on an Article's SHOW view. He is prompted to leave a review and the form contains the fields:

- rating (Review Entity)
- review title (Review Entity)
- name (Author Entity)
- email (Author Entity)

Notice we should NOT display any fields requested the Article being viewed! We should be able to grab that behind the scenes at some point and populate the new Review's article_id in the code.

I've been working on this for a while and I think it's going to have to do something with forms and events? Here's where I'm at (which is not far...)

In this attempt I was considering just getting the fields to autopopulate and then use hidden fields.... I'd MUCH RATHER NOT DO THAT. I don't like giving people a chance to be able to manipulate article_id

```
class ReviewType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('review')->add('title');

        //$builder->add('article', HiddenType::class);

        $builder->add('author', AuthorType::class, array("label" => FALSE));

        $builder->add('rating', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => array('1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' =>'5'),
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => false
        ));

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (\Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $data = $event->getData();

                $article = $data->getArticle();
                $articleId = null === $article ? array() : $article->getId();
                $form->add('article', ArticleType::class, array("label" => FALSE));

            }
        );

    }
```

Thanks in advance for any input you can provide!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the action of your form, generated and displayed in `article/{id}/show`, to something like `article/{id}/review` and then get the article id in the corresponding action where you manage form submission and persistence.
I think this is not a matter of form events.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great idea. So if you don't mind, let me clarify some things I'm still confused on: we'd still build the form in ArticleType->buildForm correct? If I add in the author and review form elements wouldn't that mess up my standard add/edit article form? I'm not sure how to handle this. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes you can build the form as usual. You should remove the `author` field from the `ReviewType` and the `addEventListener`. Then you can set the author id and the article id in the controller where you manage the persistence of the Review. Why -1?

Comment: Ok that's perfect, thanks so much for the help. I'm not sure why/who gave the downvote. Stinks they didn't even give a reason but your solution works perfectly for me.